# Cannot send intent to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My searches didn't make me find any solutions, maybe something more simple make my code not working.

My activity javapage contain this inside the OnCreate:

```
Intent MyCountryCodeIntent = new Intent(this,OutgoingCallReceiver.class);
MyCountryCode = "01";
MyCountryCodeIntent.putExtra("code",MyCountryCode);
```

Even if I set `startActivity(MyCountryCodeIntent);` or `sendBroadcast(MyCountryCodeIntent);`
this app hangs

My OutgoingCallReceiver.class page contain this inside the onReceive:

```
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
 if(null == bundle) return;
 String MyCountryCodeIntent=intent.getStringExtra("code");
```

Maybe something wrong but I cannot find out what ..

Comment: You should specify a 'Intent action' instead of using a direct intent to a broadcast. Hence the name 'broadcast'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the Intent through Intent like this

```
Intent getextras=getIntent();
```

Than you have to get the specific type of intent like if you have sent a String from previous activity you will have to catch the Intent of String type like this

```
String s= getextras.getStringExtra(name);
```

simillarly

```
Bundle b = getextras.getBundleExtra(bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

`sendBroadcast` method should be used to invoke `BroadcastReceiver`

Below snippet will help you.

```
Intent MyCountryCodeIntent = new Intent("com.get.broadcast");
MyCountryCodeIntent.putExtra("code","01");
sendBroadcast(MyCountryCodeIntent);
```

You should register `OutgoingCallReceiver` for action `com.get.broadcast`

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("com.get.broadcast");
registerReceiver(new OutgoingCallReceiver(),filter);
```

Inside onReceive you will able to use the value.

You should go through following post to get more details.

http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/01/android-sending-receiving-broadcast-messages/

Comment: @Georges If you have got the solution for your question.Then please close the question by accepting the correct answer.

Comment: May I ask you how should I register OutgoingCallReceiver for action com.get.broadcast ?

Comment: Sorry but I'm really newbie ...
Could you spent more time with me ? 
here the Two files http://goo.gl/8cVwY and http://goo.gl/Bg58u Thanks a lot if U could tell me where I'm wrong... maybe evrywhere